Flask post order
In flask when there is a post and I collect the information by request.form.to_dict() does this come from the HTML form in a ordered fashion as top to bottom? I was told that if I do it as request.form.to_dict(flat=False) that this would improve the order but this appears to just make it a dictionary with key : [values]. If it is all ordered I can collect data in an ordered fashion and send to the database but I worry that things might not be ordered.
